# Server program to communicate with iOS, android and windows

Tags: php, android, ios, json, windows-phone-7

Im planning to write a server program to communicate with iOs, android and windows phone, which would be the best language to choose. I was planning on using PHP and JSON but still confused that if it is the most efficient. Anyone with experience on this can help me pls...
Please do not mistake me if its a stupid question I'm still a beginner...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use parse.com. parse.com provides API's for all the devices you listed, and what they call "cloud code" (javascript) that can perform custom operations as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It completely depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are really good with php you can use it or, you can use languages such as node.js to do this. Right now we are using node.js and mongo db to save some data on our servers and sending push notification to users.

I would recommend checking parse.com API's for your backend services. They have a free tier where most of the applications will fit. If you are really sure you will have more than 1 million requests every month, then you can start thinking of your own back end.  If you are writing your own backend and if you are good with javascript, node.js is your friend along with mongo db.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response....ll check out node.js and parse.com...;)